# Python: Resetting a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

For the below code, after running `start_point = start_point / 10`, its value drops to 1,000 and would remain as such if it is called subsequently.

May I know how to reset it to the 10,000 it originally was? I believe one method would be to set a global variable. But is there a simpler way? Like a `seek(0)`?

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500                 
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000                   
    crates = jars / 100                         
    return jelly_beans, crates, jars                

start_point = 10000
item_1, item_2, item_3 = secret_formula(start_point)

print "With a starting point of: %d" % start_point
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (item_1, item_2, item_3)

start_point = start_point / 10

print "We can also do that this way:"
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)
```

Comment: Why do you even save the new value, if you're gonna reset it afterwards anyways? Why not just `print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point / 10)` instead?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Should have done that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would creating another variable work?

```
original_start_point = 1000
start_point = original_start_point
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. This way the OP may always revert to the desired *"original value"* with `start_point = original_start_point` provided that they only change the `start_point` variable and don't work with `original_start_point` otherwise (it doesn't get modified).

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it satisfies your question